# Puppeteer: Save data from a for loop in database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm web-scraping a site and managed to extract data in the for loop.

However, I don't know how can I save it to my MongoDB database as I'm receiving an error `ReferenceError: nameElement is not defined` .

How can I save the results from my for loop as an object to my database?

```
const kclResults = [];

async function scrapeInfiniteScrollItems(
  page,
  scrollDelay = 10000
) {
  try {
    const html = await page.content();
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    await page.evaluate(() => {
      let elements = $("[role='listitem']")
        .find("._2DX0iPG8PDF3Si_o5PlzIj")
        .toArray();

      for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        $(elements[i]).click();
        const nameElement = $("[data-log-name='PersonName']").text();
        const emailElement = $("[data-log-name='Email']").text();
        const allElements = $("[aria-label='Contact information']").text();
        const officeLocation = $("[data-log-name='OfficeLocation']").text();
        const position = $("[data-log-name='Company']").text();
        const jobTitle = $("[data-log-name='JobTitle']").text();
        const departament = $("[data-log-name='Department']").text();
        console.log(
          `email: ${emailElement} name: ${nameElement} allElements: ${allElements} \n office location: ${officeLocation} \n position: ${position} \n jobTitle: ${jobTitle} \n departament: ${departament}`
        );
      }
    });


    let kclResult = new KingsDB({
      nameElement,
      emailElement,
      allElements,
      officeLocation,
      position,
      jobTitle,
      departament,
    });

    kclResults.push(kclResult);
    console.log(kclResults);
    kclResult.save();
    return kclResults;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are declaring `nameElement` in for loop scope and trying to access it outside that scope. This Is what is causing the error

Comment: When I move it inside of the loop I get another error ```Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: KingsDB is not defined``` which I have defined before ```const KingsDB = require("./KingsDB");```

Comment: That's weird can you post the whole code.

Comment: Or wait.., are you trying to access `KingsDB` inside your pageEvaluate function?

Comment: yes, exactly trying to access it inside of pageEvaluate function

Comment: Ahh, the error makes sense then. The function passed to `pageEvaluate` runs in browserContext and thus doesn't have access to your node variables, until explicitly passed as an argument.

Comment: I would recommend returning an array from pageEvaluate function and then iterate over it to write it to your DB outside of the browser context. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `nameElement` (and other variables) in for loop scope and trying to access it outside that scope.

Just create an array of "elements" and iterate over it when you're writing it to your DB. This code below should work:

```
const kclResults = [];

async function scrapeInfiniteScrollItems(
    page,
    scrollDelay = 10000
) {
    try {
        const html = await page.content();
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);



        const resultArr = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let elements = $("[role='listitem']")
                .find("._2DX0iPG8PDF3Si_o5PlzIj")
                .toArray();
            const resultArr = [];

            for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                $(elements[i]).click();
                const nameElement = $("[data-log-name='PersonName']").text();
                const emailElement = $("[data-log-name='Email']").text();
                const allElements = $("[aria-label='Contact information']").text();
                const officeLocation = $("[data-log-name='OfficeLocation']").text();
                const position = $("[data-log-name='Company']").text();
                const jobTitle = $("[data-log-name='JobTitle']").text();
                const departament = $("[data-log-name='Department']").text();
                resultArr.push({
                    nameElement,
                    emailElement,
                    allElements,
                    officeLocation,
                    position,
                    jobTitle,
                    departament
                });
                console.log(
                    `email: ${emailElement} name: ${nameElement} allElements: ${allElements} \n office location: ${officeLocation} \n position: ${position} \n jobTitle: ${jobTitle} \n departament: ${departament}`
                );
            }
            return resultArr;

        });

        const kclResults = [];
        for (let result of resultArr) {
            const {
                nameElement,
                emailElement,
                allElements,
                officeLocation,
                position,
                jobTitle,
                departament
            } = result;
            let kclResult = new KingsDB({
                nameElement,
                emailElement,
                allElements,
                officeLocation,
                position,
                jobTitle,
                departament,
            });

            kclResults.push(kclResult);
            console.log(kclResults);
            kclResults.push(kclResult.save());
        }
        return kclResults;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

**PS**: The function passed to pageEvaluate runs in browser context and thus doesn't have access to your node variables, until they are explicitly passed as an argument.

Comment: Thank you - it almost works - it does save only the first object from the array and does not loop through the rest of objects anymore. It's weird as it's in a for loop already. Do you have any ideas why it only saves the first object from the array?

Comment: @Christopher Oh my bad, I was returning the array inside the for loop. Updated the answer to fix that